# Multiple intersection hooks to control multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I'm trying to implement an horizontal scroll with scroll left and right buttons [like the one in netflix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baBxJ.png).

My problem here is refs and hooks being used in multiple items.

I need separate states for separate elements in a group.

I tried using react-intersection-observer but again it's meant to be used with only one element and development becomes absurd when tricked with multiple refs.

```
const refs = React.useRef<Array<InView | null>>([]);

{
  array.map((service, index) => {
    return (
      <InView
        as="div"
        threshold={1}
        onChange={(inView, entry) => {
         //Manually set the inView state of ref
          refs.current[index]?.setState({ inView: inView });
        }}
        ref={(el: any | null) => (refs.current[index] = el)}
        id={`${index}`}
        key={index}
      >
       <div></div>
      </InView>
    );
  });
}
```

plus, having to wrap a hole component in another complex component just to check if it's visible to user looked like too much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have an easier time achieving your goal if you use
[Material UI Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel) package for example.